# Why am I getting an error when trying to assign a CRS to a raster in R?

Tags: r, spatial, raster

I am creating rasters with the raster package in R and I would like to explicitly specify the coordinate reference system (CRS) for the raster so that it will be coded into the geotif when I use writeRaster() to save the object to a file. I have attempted to specify the CRS as indicated in the help file for the raster() function, but it is returning an unused argument error as seen in the minimal working example below.

Why is this failing and how can I set the CRS for the raster?

```
library(raster)
set.seed(2013)
df <- data.frame( x = rep( 0:1, each=2 ),
                  y = rep( 0:1,  2),
                  l = rnorm( 4 ))

spg <- df
coordinates(spg) <- ~ x + y
gridded(spg) <- TRUE

rasterDF <- raster(spg, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
# Error in .local(x, ...) : 
#   unused argument (crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

Comment: @tim riffe, thanks for catching my omission of the library call.

Comment: The *reason* it didn't work is because there is no `crs` argument when you are trying to create a raster from `SpatialPointsDataFrame`. If you look down the usage list of the help page for `?raster` you will see what arguments are available for each type of object you are converting. Instead either do it as @ialm suggests or make the raster without projection information and add it after via `projection(rasterDF) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"`, or even better  via `projection(rasterDF) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")` so the CRS function can check you have a valid CRS string. Phew!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the projection to your spatial data frame using `proj4string(spg) <- "your CRS"` before creating a raster object. The projection information should carry over to your newly created raster layer.

This works for me:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(2013)
df <- data.frame( x = rep( 0:1, each=2 ),
                  y = rep( 0:1,  2),
                  l = rnorm( 4 ))

spg <- df
coordinates(spg) <- ~ x + y
gridded(spg) <- TRUE

# Add the projection information to spg
proj4string(spg) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

rasterDF <- raster(spg)

# Check that it worked
rasterDF
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 2, 2, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
# extent      : -0.5, 1.5, -0.5, 1.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# data source : in memory
# names       : l 
# values      : -0.6674423, 1.360611  (min, max)
```